# sql query one table with customizing order

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have one table which i hope to sort in an ordering with a few different conditions/priorities in one query.

For example, with a table named 'User' comes with 5 columns:

```
userID
userName
age
gender
birthday
```

In the case where age, gender and birthday may be null, I hope the query will return the table rows in the priority order of:

```
1. Age, gender and birthday is not null,
2. Age, gender is not null,
3. Age is not null,
4. Then the rest of the rows
```

I looked into UNION, UNION ALL and ORDER BY IF, but didnt manage to achieve the result (maybe I queried wrongly).

Hope someone could help me out with this. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple matter of an order by:

```
order by (case when age is not null and birthday is not null and gender is not null then 1
               when age is not null and birthday is not null then 2
               when age is not null then 3
               else 4
          end)
```

You can add additional sort criteria afterwards as well (such as name or whatever).

For instance, to sort by age in descending order within each case:

```
order by (case when age is not null and birthday is not null and gender is not null then 1
               when age is not null and birthday is not null then 2
               when age is not null then 3
               else 4
          end),
         age desc
```

Comment: hi, what does "1","2","4" mean? is it the display order?

Comment: It actually means 1, 2, 3, 4 (typo on the third).  Yes, these are the values used by order by, so the first condition comes first and so on.

Comment: and how do i sort by age in descending order for each case?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear as to the conditions that need to be met for each priority, but you'll get the idea from this:

```
select   *
from     mytable
order by 
         case when age is null and gender is null and birthday is null then 1
              when age is null and gender is null and birthday is not null then 2
              when age is null and gender is not null and birthday is not null then 3
              when age is not null and gender is not null and birthday is not null then 4
              else 5
         end
```

Edit: I think I read your question wrong because of the lack of formatting and I got the NULLs mixed up with NOT NULLs, but you get the idea...